# CursorTreeAdapter and getChildType

Tags: java, android, android-cursoradapter

I'm trying to use `custom CursorTreeAdapter` with two different types of child items.
I want to use `getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition)` method inside `newChildView` method

```
 @Override
 protected View newChildView(Context context, Cursor cursor,boolean isLastChild, ViewGroup parent)   {
    View view = null;

    switch(getChildType(**groupPosition**, cursor.getPosition())){
    case TYPE_CHILD_1:
        view = inflater.inflate(...);
    break;
    case TYPE_CHILD_2:
        view = inflater.inflate(...);
    break;
    }
    return view;
}
```

But there is no `groupPosition arg` inside `newChildView` method. How can I get `groupPosition`?

Answer (score 0):

check bindView method

```
public void bindView(View arg0, Context arg1, Cursor arg2)
{
    int pos = arg2.getPosition();
}
```

here arg2 is for group.

Comment: CursorTreeAdapter has only bindChildView and bindGroupView methods. These methods called after newChildView.